# Rendering custom navbar items

Tags: html, css, angular

here is my application.

https://stackblitz.com/github/tsingh38/lastrada

i am having problem with the navigation 
Component → NavbarComponent

[image: Navigation]

My aim is to have a navigation bar in which different links will be shown. Each link will route to a Component.

Clicking direct on the links is working fine.There are 2 arrow links which should also navigate to either next or previous component respectively.

```
  <div *ngIf="!isSearchBarActive">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs"   style="margin-left: 50px;">
            <a  [routerLink]="[menuBarItemsInitView[0]]" (click)="onLeftClick()" *ngIf="isLeftClickEnabled"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
            <li role="presentation" *ngFor="let item of menuBarItemsInitView let i=index"><a  

                 [routerLink]="[item]"
                 routerLinkActive="active" 
                 [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
                    true}"
                    style="color:gray">{{item}}</a></li>
            <a [routerLink]="[menuBarItemsInitView[1]]" (click)="onRightClick()"   style="margin-left: 3em;" *ngIf="ifRightClickEnabled"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Problem 1:
on right click it goes to the right component but left click does not go to the right component.

menuBarItemsInitView array includes currently shown links in the navbar.
menuBarItemsInitView[0] this is where i am pointing to on left click  and menuBarItemsInitView[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnUFd.png) on right click. 
i thought it should be menuBarItemsInitView[0] to point to the first element on left or right click but unfortunately it does not point/route to the correct component. it seems like router link does not get the right value at the time click event is executed.

Problem 2:

has nothing to do with angular but i am struggling to fit all the elements in navbar.As of now it looks ugly since there is a lot of empty space on right side.Do i need to calculate dynamically the length of the cell ?

[image: emptyspace]

I tried dividing the search div and navigation div into equals length using col-sm-XX but then on clicking right button it splits into 2 rows which is super ugly.

Any pointers how to achieve fixed width irrespective of the length of the text of the menu items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: I think you have some issues when scrolling items. Here is a simple version of your code that works on the left/right scrolling.

```
export class AppComponent {
  menuBarItemsAll:String[]=['Pizza','Indisch','Salat','Italinisch','Drink','AlkohalfreiGetäanke','Pide','Donör','Something1','Someething2','AlkohalfreiGetäanke','Something3','Someething21','Someething25']
  menuBarItemsInitView:String[];  
  initStartIndex=0;
  initNumberOfItemsToShow=5;
  isLeftClickEnabled=false;
  isRightClickEnabled=false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateItemsInView(this.initStartIndex);
  }
  onLeftClick() {
    this.updateItemsInView(this.initStartIndex-1);
  }
  onRightClick() {
    this.updateItemsInView(this.initStartIndex+1);
  }
  updateItemsInView(indexStart:number){
    const lMin = 0;
    const lMax = this.menuBarItemsAll.length-this.initNumberOfItemsToShow;
    if (indexStart<lMin) indexStart = lMin;
    if (indexStart>lMax) indexStart = lMax;
    this.initStartIndex = indexStart;
    this.isLeftClickEnabled = indexStart > lMin;
    this.isRightClickEnabled = indexStart < lMax;
    this.menuBarItemsInitView = this.menuBarItemsAll.slice(indexStart, indexStart+this.initNumberOfItemsToShow);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button *ngIf="isLeftClickEnabled" (click)="onLeftClick()">LEFT</button>
    <span *ngFor="let item of menuBarItemsInitView">({{item}})</span>   
    <button *ngIf="isRightClickEnabled" (click)="onRightClick()">RIGHT</button>
</div>
```

Problem 2: As you mentioned that you find it "ugly" I would suggest to look for a new way of presentation without having to "calculate" widths. Something responsive, user friendly, using CSS, without manual calculations.